# Shed under power lines

Tags: code-compliance, shed

I wish to build a shed, but the location I want to use has an overhead power cable running from the utility pole to the neighbor's house.  The line has about 12' of clearance from the ground.

Is there a minimum clearance for overhead lines over a shed? Or is the site just not feasible?

Comment: That's pretty odd their overhead is running across your property. Kind of a dumb question; you're sure it's running over your property, opposed to just thinking it's yours because you've used and maintained it for n years etc?

Comment: What pitch is the roof on the planned shed? (Yes, it actually matters, bigtime even)

Comment: I've got the neighbors service drop running through the air across my property. Must not be too uncommon...

Comment: is that shown as a right-of-way on your deed/survey?

Comment: The utility pole is in the rear middle of our yard. From there it distributes power to both our houses, with the line to the neighbors crossing our yard at a diagonal.